# MVC API: Structuring XML Response with child elements

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, api, structure

Very new to MVC. I am currently writing an API and have a strict format that I need the XML to be returned in.

At the moment, I am using my EntityModel to expose my SQL Stored procedure. I have then created an Complex Type for the SP.

I have a controller that is calling the SP and the results are returned in XML.

This is fine however, the output is currently (for example):

```
    <product> 
        <productId>12345</productId> 
        <inStock>True</inStock> 
        <shelfLevel>10</shelfLevel> 
        <onOrder>0</onOrder> 
        <height>10</height> 
        <width>15</width> 
        <depth>12</depth> 
        <colour>green</colour> 
    </product>
```

However, it needs to be structured as:

```
   <product> 
        <productId>12345</productId> 
        <availability> 
                <inStock>True</inStock> 
                <shelfLevel>10</shelfLevel> 
                <onOrder>0</onOrder> 
        </availability> 
        <dimensions> 
                <height>10</height> 
                <width>15</width> 
                <depth>12</depth> 
        </dimensions> 
        <colour>green</colour> 
   </product>
```

I can not see any way of including the 'availabilty' and 'dimensions' wrapper elements using my current approach of EntityModel and Complex Type combination.

Below is my code from the controller for the existing output:

```
// GET api/product/5 

        //ProductAvailability_Result is the Complex Type derived from the SP output columns 
        public IEnumerable<ProductAvailability_Result> Get(int id) 
        { 

           myDB_DevEntities db = new myDB_DevEntities(); 

           //ProductAvailability is a SP consisting of a simple 'select' statement that returns the resultset 
           var Result = db.ProductAvailability(id); 

           return Result.ToList(); 

        }
```

Can anyone give any pointers on how to achieve this? Am i approaching this on completly the wrong way by trying to use the above method i.e. should I be ditching EntityModel? It works great until I need to change the structure.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DTO ([data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) that looks like way you'd like, but you'd have to do a little bit of data transformation. You'd start with defining the class structure that matches the structure of the expected XML:

```
[XmlRoot("product")]
public class ProductDto
{
    [XmlElement("productId")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("availability")]
    public AvailabilityDto Availability { get; set; }

    ...
}

[XmlRoot("availability")]
public class AvailabilityDto
{
    [XmlElement("inStock")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And then in your API method you can transform your DAO (data access object) into your DTO before you return it to the client:

```
public ProductDto GetProductAvailability(id)
{
    var result = db.ProductAvailability(id); 

    return new ProductDto
    {
        ProductId = result.productId,
        Availability = new AvailabilityDto
        {
             InStock = result.inStock,
             ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously this could amount to a ton of work, so I too am curious what other answers to your question may pop up.